# How to animate on entrance SVG images gradually with reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, svg, flexbox

I'm quite new to React,

I have imported an SVG and would like to **animate** few clones of it, eventually they will end up in the same row, should i be using use flexbox?

I have done it **statically** using flexbox, but i would like to animate each svg component so they will appear on the screen gradually (one after the other). Any suggestions how to accomplish it?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GSAP (GreenSock)` library to achieve that, just trigger the animation after `componentDidLoad()` in your React component.

You can learn about `GSAP` staggering here:
https://greensock.com/stagger

Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem, I haven’t use anime.js yet but that would work the same as GSAP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSSTransitionGroup for react
here are doct from react to do it
 https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup
 https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

this animations works on enter and leave from dom of element

```
<CSSTransitionGroup
transitionName="example"
transitionEnterTimeout={300}
transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
 />
<CSSTransitionGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you!
it's for storytelling, so i'm looking for few better effects